# SharpMap for asp.net 2022

Tags: sharpmap

I'm new to SharpMap and trying to display simple shapefiles.
My projection is NAD_1983_StatePlane_Alabama_East_FIPS_0101_Feet.
I cannot get the map to show up in VS 2022.

My solution that is not working right now.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace SharpMapII
{
    public partial class GIS : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private SharpMap.Map myMap;



   

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myMap = InitializeMap(new System.Drawing.Size((int)imgMap.Width.Value, (int)imgMap.Height.Value));
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Page is post back. Restore center and zoom-values from viewstate
                //myMap.Center = (SharpMap.Geometries.Point)ViewState["mapCenter"];
                myMap.Zoom = (double)ViewState["mapZoom"];
            }
            else
            {
                //This is the initial view of the map. Zoom to the extents of the map:
                myMap.ZoomToExtents();
                //Save the current mapcenter and zoom in the viewstate
                ViewState.Add("mapCenter", myMap.Center);
                ViewState.Add("mapZoom", myMap.Zoom);
                //Create the map
                CreateMap();
            }
        
        
        
            //ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory csf = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            //ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory ctf = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
            //SharpMap.Session.Instance.SetCoordinateSystemServices(new SharpMap.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemServices(csf, ctf, SharpMap.Converters.WellKnownText.SpatialReference.GetAllReferenceSystems()));
        
            //SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer layBuilding = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("Building");
            //layBuilding.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_data\Building.shp"), false);
            //layBuilding.Style.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            //layBuilding.Style.Outline = System.Drawing.Pens.Black;
            //layBuilding.Style.EnableOutline = true;
        
            //SharpMap.Map myMap = new SharpMap.Map(new Size(400, 200));
            ////Add the layer
        
            //myMap.Layers.Add(layBuilding);
            ////Zoom the map to the extents of all added layers:
        
            //myMap.ZoomToExtents();
            ////Render the map
        
            //System.Drawing.Image imgMap = myMap.GetMap();
        
        }
        
        private SharpMap.Map InitializeMap(System.Drawing.Size outputsize)
        {
            ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory csf = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory ctf = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
            SharpMap.Session.Instance.SetCoordinateSystemServices(new SharpMap.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemServices(csf, ctf, SharpMap.Converters.WellKnownText.SpatialReference.GetAllReferenceSystems()));
        
        
            //Initialize a new map of size 'imagesize'
            SharpMap.Map map = new SharpMap.Map(outputsize);
        
            //Set up the countries layer
            SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer layCountries = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("Building");
            //Set the datasource to a shapefile in the App_data folder
            layCountries.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_data\Building.shp"), true);
            //Set fill-style to green
            layCountries.Style.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            //Set the polygons to have a black outline
            layCountries.Style.Outline = System.Drawing.Pens.Black;
            layCountries.Style.EnableOutline = true;
        
           
        
            //Add the layers to the map object.
            //The order we add them in are the order they are drawn, so we add the rivers last to put them on top
            map.Layers.Add(layCountries);
        
            return map;
        }
        
        private void CreateMap()
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = myMap.GetMap();
            string imgID = SharpMap.Web.Caching.InsertIntoCache(1, img);
            imgMap.ImageUrl = "getmap.aspx?ID=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(imgID);
        }
        
        protected void imgMap_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            myMap.Center = SharpMap.Utilities.Transform.MapToWorld(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y), myMap);
            ////Set zoom value if any of the zoom tools were selected
            //if (rblMapTools.SelectedValue == "0") //Zoom in
            //    myMap.Zoom = myMap.Zoom * 0.5;
            //else if (rblMapTools.SelectedValue == "1") //Zoom out
            //    myMap.Zoom = myMap.Zoom * 2;
            ////Save the new map's zoom and center in the viewstate
            //ViewState.Add("mapCenter", myMap.Center);
            //ViewState.Add("mapZoom", myMap.Zoom);
            ////Create the map
            CreateMap();
        }
    
    }

}
```